# Disable SSL verification in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, axios

I'm trying to disable angular SSL verification in axios. I've tried using

```
axios.get(url, {
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
})
```

but it display an error `Cannot find name 'https'.ts(2304)`. So I imported `https` and then its throw a new error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https'`

Is there a way to disable SSL verification in angular with axios ?

Answer (score -1):

You can configure axios to use a custom agent:

**INSTANCE**

```
const instance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
});
instance.get('https://something.com/foo');
```

**REQUEST**

```
const request= new https.Agent({  
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});
axios.get('https://something.com/foo', { httpsAgent: request});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: like what I mention on the question, somehow there is an error when using `https` module